# Importar celda con funcion de excel en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

**Hola** Estoy ingresando datos de un archivo `excel` a mi base de datos con la libreria de `laravel excel 3.1` pero me encuentro con un problema, una celda de mi `excel` tiene lo siguiente =

`='D:\[Bitácora Calibración 2019.xlsm]Aguas'!M6`

Esa funcion me llama un texto de dicho archivo, el problema que tengo es que al llamar la celda e importarla a mi base de datos la inserta así en mi campo

```
=[1]Aguas!M6
```

Busco insertar el texto que me trae esa funcion como podria lograrlo?
Adjunto la funcion de como estoy haciendo el import:

```
 public function model(array $row)
{
 return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row[0],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row[4],
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row[6],
        'ins_nSerie' => $row[1],
        'ins_divOescala'=>$row[5],
        'ins_claseOexactitud' =>$row[6] ,
        'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row[7],
        'ins_observaciones' =>$row[8],
        'ins_observacionFinal' => $row[9],
        'ins_magnitud' => $row[10],
        'ins_modelo' => $row[11],
        'ins_codActividad' => $row[12],
        'ins_area' => 'null',
        'ins_usu_id' =>  $id,
        'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca->mar_id,
    ]);

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`='D:\[Bitácora Calibración 2019.xlsm]Aguas'!M6`

Esto lo esta yendo a buscar a otro excel? o es otra pestaña del mismo excel?

Comment: Lo busca en otro archivo excel, procura no hacer un comentario como respuesta, fijate abajo de la pregunta puedes comentar